# d3 zoom: independent X and Y zoom based on pinch angle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, touch, pinchzoom

I have a two-dimensional svg chart made with d3, which uses d3.behavior.zoom() for zooming with both mousewheel and pinch gesture on touch devices.

It works great but i would like to be able to zoom only X or only Y independently when pinch is directed mostly along one of the axes. If pinch goes diagonal let it zoom both X and Y like it does now.

Any suggestions on the approach that is best to take here?